# How to add strong SEO information in wordpress website?

Tags: html, wordpress, search, web, seo

How to add strong SEO info in word press website? Please need full answer. Thanks. I want to make my website easily to be search regarding TAGS or search keywords, related to my website. I want my web to be on first search page. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a SEO question not related to programming

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of SEO plugins available for WordPress, some better than others, but in order to truly optimize your site for search engines, you need to get a firm grasp on SEO practices in general. You'd have to learn what type of content you want, html structure, links, etc. Your best bet is to search and read plenty of articles about website SEO, and then, if you've got specific questions, ask them instead.

A quick search returned a few resources produced by Google:

[How Google Search Works](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/70897)

[How Does Google Search Work (Youtube Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyCYyoGusqs)

[Steps to a Google-Friendly Site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/40349?hl=en&ref_topic=2370419)

Mozilla has created a nice [Beginner SEO Guide](http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo) as well.

Something else to keep in mind is that Google recently announced changes to searches on Mobile Devices. If your site is not optimized for mobile devices, your ranking will drop. So make sure to build a responsive site.

SEO is a constantly evolving aspect of the web, so you will also need to continually follow industry trends in order to maintain strong SEO.